# Ist das Tiefschwa allein, oder hat es mit dem Hochschwa ein kleines Brüd​ɐ​chen?

Tags: phonetics

Jüngst stoße ich in Beiträgen zu diesem Forum vermehrt auf den Begriff *Tiefschwa* für den fast offenen Zentralvokal ​ɐ​ - also etwa wie das *er* in *Brüd**er**chen*.

Der Name *Tiefschwa* ist zwar von den Aussprachegewohnheiten her einleuchtend. Aber wenn es ein *Tiefschwa* gibt (oder die Notwendigkeit einer solchen Abgrenzung von einem nicht weiter spezifizierten Schwa), gibt es dann auch ein Hochschwa?

Die Eingabe der Suchtermini "Tiefschwa Hochschwa" in eine Internet-Suchmaschine ergab bei mir genau Null Treff​ɐ​. Eine Maschinensuche nach "Hochschwa" führte mich in den Hochschwarzwald.

Wissen Forum-Les​ɐ​ me​ɐ​?

Warum sagt man zum e-Schwa (danke an den Kommentator CarstenS!) nicht *Hochschwa*?

Comment: Du kannst nach dem e-Schwa im Gegensatz zum a-Schwa suchen.

Comment: @CarstenS  Danke, damit kommen wir der Antwort ein**e** Spur häh**er**, aber eigenartigerweise sagt man nicht "Hochschwa" dazu, oder?

Comment: Keine Ahnung, aber ich nehme an, dass das andere Schwa einfach das „normale“ ist und daher keinen besonderen Namen hat.

Answer (score 2):

My answer is only a personal opinion and reflects how I understand the IPA terminology. If you take a look at [the formal chart of IPA](https://linguistics.ucla.edu/people/keating/IPA/IPA_DejaVu_2018_full.pdf), you can see how and where each vowel is represented:

[image]

They are represented in a polygonal shape that depicts the oral cavity. Each vowel is described by terms that indicate its position in the oral cavity such as *front, centeral, back* on the anterior-posterior axis, and *close, mid, open* on the superior-inferior axis of the oral cavity. Each vowel is described according to its **position in the oral cavity**. Vowels **are not described according to their relative positions to each others.**

E-schwa is defined as:

> - Its vowel height is mid, which means the tongue is positioned halfway between a close vowel and an open vowel.
> - Its vowel backness is central, which means the tongue is positioned halfway between a front vowel and a back vowel.
> - It is unrounded, which means that the lips are not rounded.

This schwa **can not** be described as ***high**schwa or *Hochschwa because it does not occur in the upper half of the oral cavity.

A-schwa is defined:

> - Its vowel height is near-open, also known as near-low, which means the tongue is positioned similarly to an open vowel, but is slightly more constricted – that is, the tongue is positioned similarly to a low vowel, but slightly higher.
> - Its vowel backness is central, which means the tongue is positioned halfway between a front vowel and a back vowel.
> - It is rounded, which means that the lips are rounded rather than spread or relaxed.

This schwa occurs in the lower half of the oral cavity, so describing it as a *low* schwa (*Tiefschwa*) is legitimate.

In conclusion, there is a schwa, there is a *Tiefschwa*, but there can not be a *Hochschwa.

Comment: Some variants of English distinguish between the unstressed vowels in _Rosa's_ and _roses_. The latter is sometimes called a high schwa, or even schwi.

Comment: @MarcSchütz That is no doubt possible. The previous chart is only about the standard language. If we want to consider dialects, I have seen more than 10 other different charts that represent the major dialects in US. Each dialect has its own chart and its own set of phonemes and vowels.